# EXCEL VBA/Macro commands revision

Tags: excel, vba

Update:

Button 1 now works on all sheets, but what would be cool is that after sorting, it would not only highlight A7, but also jump the entire view there with the "view/camera". For example, if you are on Z44 and click on sort, you will get to A7.

```
' Sortieren Button
Sub Sortieren()
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With Sht
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            LastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("B7:B" & LastRow), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With .Sort
                .SetRange Range("B7:XFD75")
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
            .Select
            .[A7].Select
        End With
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: The table is fixed from 1 to 6 and A to D. It shifts down and to the right.]

The table is fixed from 1 to 6 and A to D. It shifts down and to the right.

---

---

I am working on a document where I have inserted command buttons to make my work easier. I have problems with 2 buttons.

The first button is about sorting the table contents alphabetically. However, it only sorts the first worksheet and not the entire workbook. Can someone please correct the code?

```
' Sortieren Button
Sub Sortieren()
    Range("B7:XFD1048576").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WINTERGARTEN").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WINTERGARTEN").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B7:B75"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WINTERGARTEN").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B7:XFD76")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

The second is about jumping to today. Here I have 2 problems. The first problem is the same as before. It should execute this command for every worksheet. Furthermore, it would be nice if today's day appeared on the left and not in the middle of the screen.

[image: Here it jumps to today's date, but it is in the middle.]

[image: It would be much nicer if it displayed today's date all the way to the left.]

```
' Heute Button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lngZeile As Long
Dim lngSpalte As Long
Dim suchDatum As Date

suchDatum = Date
lngZeile = 5
For lngSpalte = Range("U5").Column To Range("HS5").Column
    If IsDate(Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value) Then
        If CDate(Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value) = suchDatum Then
             Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next lngSpalte
End Sub
```

And somehow I can't get it right. Can someone please help me? :)

A lot of things, I searched on the internet, but I'm probably not experienced enough. Before this "work" I had no idea about all this.

Comment: Have you considered a loop to go through the worksheets?

Comment: Please, just one question per post.

Comment: @ Foxfire: Sorry. I'll keep it in mind!
@ Solar Mike: No, I have no idea. I put together what I have/can. It's a private document for home. I am not from the field. :) Of course, better ways are also welcome. I just kind of did it all.

Answer (score 0):

*Button1*: Loop through all worksheet and sort the table. The logic is same as your code. Using dynamic range to improve efficiency.

```vb
' Sortieren Button
Sub Sortieren()
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With Sht
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            LastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("B7:B" & LastRow), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With .Sort
                .SetRange .Range(.[B7], .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
            .Select
            .[A7].Select  ' Requirement from comment
        End With
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

*Button2*: There is only one active sheet in the workbook. I guess
`jumping to today` means to scroll the column (today) to the left on the screen.

```vb
' Heute Button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lngZeile As Long
    Dim lngSpalte As Long
    Dim suchDatum As Date
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim sShtName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    suchDatum = Date
    lngZeile = 5
    sShtName = ActiveSheet.Name
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Sht.Select
        For lngSpalte = Range("U5").Column To Range("HS5").Column
            If IsDate(Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value) Then
                If CDate(Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value) = suchDatum Then
                    Cells(lngZeile, Columns.Count).Select
                    Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Select
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next lngSpalte
    Next Sht
    Sheets(sShtName).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! On the first one, it tells me to debug the following: .SetRange .Range(.[B7], .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)) What could be the error? With my Range, it works wonderfully. But I would have to adjust it every time the table gets bigger.

Comment: And on the second, it reports that I need to debug the following: Cells(lngRow, Columns.Count).Select

Comment: Button1: Do all sheets have same data layout as screenshot? Please check the value of `LastRow, LastCol`.  Button 2: `lngRow` should be `lngZeile`

Comment: Yes, they are all the same, only the buttons are only on the first sheet. The last column is HT and it goes down to row 75.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. Still reports debug on both.

Comment: Ah XFD75 would be the last possible column anyway, right? Then I can simply take myrange from .SetRange Range("B7:XFD76") and then button 1 works wonderfully :)

Comment: Is it possible that after clicking button 1 the view of all sheets jumps up to the beginning? A1, do you know what I mean? How would you have to customise the code of the first button?

Comment: `XFD75 would be the last possible column anyway, right?` - Yes, XFD is the last column.

Comment: Is it possible that after clicking button 1 the view of all sheets jumps up to the beginning? -- `Sht.Select Sht.[a1].Select`

Comment: between what, where would I have to insert it?

Comment: I have updated the code for button 1.

Comment: Ah sorry, it's A7, A1 to A6 is fixed, then nothing happens. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for the change. It ticks the box. But the "camera" does not jump there. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please update your screenshot with rows/columns heading. Then show what's the expected result. What's the `camera`?

Comment: I updated it :)

Comment: I haven't seen updated screenshot, so I don't know which cell is A7.

Comment: I finally managed to do it. xD