# Excel VBA/Macro Sort Command Button

Tags: excel, vba

I am sharing my one question from the original post here, for clarity and accuracy: [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77171847/excel-vba-macro-commands-revision)

I have programmed this button but need help to correct and improve it. I originally created it via macro recording and it has already been significantly improved for me by this forum.

But I still have an idea what would make the button even better.

- The "Sort" button should sort all sheets, not just the first sheet where the button is on. All sheets have exactly the same structure.
- After sorting, the view should jump back so that place 1 is visible, which would be A7 on each sheet. In the document, the upper area and the left area are fixed, i.e. from 1 to 6 and A to D.

Does anyone have a good idea and can help me? :)

Here, this was my first code:

```
' Sortieren Button
Sub Sortieren()
    Range("B7:XFD1048576").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WINTERGARTEN").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WINTERGARTEN").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B7:B75"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WINTERGARTEN").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B7:XFD75")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

And my current code, already optimised:

```
' Sortieren Button
Sub Sortieren()
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With Sht
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            LastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("B7:B" & LastRow), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With .Sort
                .SetRange Range("B7:XFD75")
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
            .Select
            .[A7].Select
        End With
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And this is what my Excel looks like:

[image: My Excel Workbook]

I have researched a lot on the internet, but I am probably not experienced enough. Before this "work" I had no idea about all this.

Here are my questions/problems:

- The view does not yet jump to A7. It simply highlights A7, but the view does not jump there. Is there any way to send it back to the start like again. A1 is then at the top left and the table is moved all the way up and to the left again to 1, A7?

Comment: And what is working? What is not working as expected? What is your question?

Comment: Sorry! Updated.

Comment: You can try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.goto

Comment: Great! That must be it. How would you have to adapt the code so that it catapults me to the start on sheet 1, but in the background all the other sheets also jump there in their tables, but don't catapult me around like a ping-pong? I can then just insert it below the Application.ScreenUpdating = True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sort Multiple Similar Worksheets

```vb
Sub Sortieren()

    Const BUTTON_SHEET_NAME As String = "WINTERGARTEN"
    Const FIRST_DATA_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A7"
    Const SORT_COLUMN As Long = 2
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then wb.Activate
    
    Dim aws As Worksheet: Set aws = wb.Sheets(BUTTON_SHEET_NAME)
    ' If you put a button on all worksheets, you could use...
    'Set aws = wb.ActiveSheet
    ' ... for any initially active sheet being selected finally.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, fCell As Range
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws
            Set fCell = .Range(FIRST_DATA_CELL_ADDRESS)
            With .UsedRange
                Set rg = .Worksheet.Range(fCell, .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)) 
            End With
            With .Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add Key:=rg.Columns(SORT_COLUMN), _
                    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SetRange rg
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End With
        Application.Goto Reference:=fCell, Scroll:=True
    Next ws
    
    aws.Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh man, thats perfect!!! Thank you so much!!!