# Excel VBA/Macro Jump-to-today Command Button

Tags: excel, vba

I am sharing my one question from the original post here, for clarity and accuracy: [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77171847/excel-vba-macro-commands-revision)

I have programmed this button but need help to correct and improve it. I originally created it as a command button and it has already been improved considerably by this forum, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. It always gives me a debug error.

- The Today button should jump to today's date.
- But it would also be nice if the date did not appear in the middle, but flush left. Today corresponds to the first entry.

Does anyone have a good idea and can help me? :)

Here, this was my first code:

```
' Heute Button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lngZeile As Long
Dim lngSpalte As Long
Dim suchDatum As Date

suchDatum = Date
lngZeile = 5
For lngSpalte = Range("U5").Column To Range("HS5").Column
    If IsDate(Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value) Then
        If CDate(Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value) = suchDatum Then
             Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next lngSpalte
End Sub
```

And my current code, already optimised, but with debug-error:

```
' Heute Button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lngZeile As Long
    Dim lngSpalte As Long
    Dim suchDatum As Date
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim sShtName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    suchDatum = Date
    lngZeile = 5
    sShtName = ActiveSheet.Name
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Sht.Select
        For lngSpalte = Range("U5").Column To Range("HS5").Column
            If IsDate(Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value) Then
                If CDate(Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value) = suchDatum Then
                    Cells(lngZeile, Columns.Count).Select
                    Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Select
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next lngSpalte
    Next Sht
    Sheets(sShtName).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And this is what my Excel looks like:

[image: My Excel Workbook]

I have researched a lot on the internet, but I am probably not experienced enough. Before this "work" I had no idea about all this.

Here are my questions/problems:

- The button marks the current date, but it is in the middle. It would be nice if it appeared left-aligned. Also, the current code gives a debug error: Cells(lngRow, Columns.Count).Select
- And at the moment it only jumps to the correct date on the first sheet. It would be nice if it would jump to the correct date on all sheets in the background.

When I click on the Today button, I jump to the correct date, but it always appears in the middle. Left aligned would be nice.

[image]

Comment: I think that line should be changed to Cells(lngZeile, Sht.Columns.Count).Select

Comment: That line has no meaning, **if it is followed by another selecting code line**. So, I think you can comment, delete it. Or delete the following code line and use the above suggested solution, if more convenient. Than, what do you mean by "The button marks the current date, but it is in the middle"? How does it "mark"? Which **it** to appear "left aligned"? Are you referring to **selection**? Or what? Is there in the picture such a "marker" and I am missing it?

Comment: Sorry! Updated. :)

Comment: If you want the code to jump in all sheets, you should simple comment/delete the code line: `Exit For`, coming after `Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Select`. I still do not understand what "left aligned" does mean... Is it in the picture showing **how you want**? I can see the cell, as I imagined, but what about the respective "mark"? I suppose that the black circle is place there by you in order to emphasize the found cell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the focus to a cell by using `Select`, so that part of your code is okay. This will set the `ActiveCell` (the cell that has the focus). Excel will scroll the sheet so that the active cell is visible (usually somewhat centered).

If you want to force the sheet to scroll to a specific position, you can use the `ScrollColumn` (and/or `ScrollRow`) property. However, this is a property of a `Window`-object, not of a sheet: In Excel, you can have multiple windows showing different parts of a sheet. Usually, you deal with the `ActiveWindow` object. Setting `ScrollColumn` will force that column to be at the left of the window (if feasible) or next to any frozen columns.

Your code could look like this (I changed the names of the variables and some other details, but of course it's up to you how you name variables)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const DateRow As Long = 5
    Dim col As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, currentSheet As Worksheet
    
    Dim searchDate As Date
    searchDate = Date
    
    Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With Sht
            .Select  ' Needed so you can select a cell from that sheet
        
            For col = Range("U5").Column To Range("HS5").Column
                Dim cell As Range
                Set cell = .Cells(DateRow, col)
                If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
                    If cell.Value = searchDate Then
                        cell.Select
                        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = col
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next col
        End With
    Next Sht
    
    currentSheet.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I cannot say why in your code `Cells(lngZeile, Columns.Count).Select` should issue a runtime error, but you don't need that statement anyhow - there is no reason first jump to the far right of the sheet and then move back to the left.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its perfect. :) Also very interesting to read and learn!